# Git submodules not going into repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

I added a submodule to a feature branch of my local repository.  I can see the related info in .git/config and .gitmodules.  I pushed to the remote.  `git status` shows clean.

When I clone the repo on another box and checkout the branch, I don't see .gitmodules or the entry in .git/config, and thus I cannot build my project as the dependency source code is completely missing.  Do submodules work on branches?  What did I do wrong?

EDIT: If I `git clone -b nameofbranch` it DOES check out the .gitmodules file.  It doesn't do it if I clone without specifying the branch and then checkout.  Seems like a bug to me but maybe it's intended for some reason I don't understand.

Comment: Can you paste whole workflow? Must be something else to it.

Comment: `git clone git@git.assembla.com:myrepo.git;
git checkout pdf`  not sure what else i can tell you.

Comment: I just checked the repo web interface and the .gitmodules file IS stored in the branch on the remote, but it doesn't show up when I check out that branch.

Comment: I think you need to pull: `git clone git@git.assembla.com:myrepo.git; git checkout pdf; git pull`

Comment: @rosipov i just tried your suggestion - it doesn't do anything differently.

Answer (score 0):

`git clone --recursive` is required to recursively clone each submodule. You can accomplish the same with `git submodule update` in an already cloned repo.

Answer (score 0):

before you push you might have needed this.

```
git submodule foreach git checkout -b origin/branch_name
```

here branch_name should be the branch to which you are going to push.